# Laser Diodes to work it in high temperature

Tags: led, power-electronics, led-strip, led-driver

The power of laser diodes, made of GaAs, is limited by its power loss and the maximum operating temperature. Theoretically, the semiconductor material itself can be operated up to an intrinsic temperature of 650°C. Practically the operating temperature is limited at 250°C, because the electrical contacts, made by soldering with a high lead solder (300°C melting temperature).
the question is how can make or let this component to work with high temperature is that by electrical contacts in attaches in a circuit?
That's which allow an application with a maximum of operating temperature and of course i have to consider to and ensure the thermal expansion and the mechanical stability.

Comment: The semiconductor material might not be damaged until 650 C, but that doesn't mean its performance as a laser won't go to absolute crap.

Answer (score 1):

Several things:

The power of a laser diode may be limited by the light intensity causing damage to the facets, independently of the thermal effects.  The datasheet should tell you both the maximum instantaneous (optically limited) power and the maximum average (thermally limited) power.

Attempting to run more current through the diode may not be effective because at a certain point you may run out of charge carriers.  At higher voltages the charge carriers may also be pulled out of the active region so they are not in a good location to lase.  (I am guessing here.)

Also, if your device is not designed to operate at high temperatures, it may not act properly due to the number of holes and electrons popped out of the Fermi sea by thermal effects: the free carriers act metalish instead of semiconductorish and just conduct without providing any light.  Even at more conventional temperatures, laser diode efficiency drops significantly just going from 20C to 50C.

Answer (score 1):

> Practically the operating temperature is limited at 250°C, because
>   the electrical contacts, made by soldering with a high lead solder
>   (300°C melting temperature).

Not true, wires are bonded, sometimes welded, never soldered.

Photon emitting devices are designed to work within a specified temperature range.  The size of the bandgap determines the wavelength.

A GaAs bandgap shrinks as temperature rises.

[image]

source: *The Handbook of Photonics  2nd Edition*

Comment: Can you expand this to make the connection of how this effect determines whether a laser can or can't be made to operate at high temperature?

Comment: If one could come up with a sane reason to want it to operate at a high temperature.   If it works well at room temperature, why would you want it to generate heat for no apparent reason?  Properties of materials change with temperature, especially photon emitting materials.  Flux, Vf, and chromaticity are very temperature sensitive.

Comment: Typical use cases for high temperature devices are things like industrial control of a furnace or down-well devices for oil drilling. You don't want the device to heat itself to 250 C, you want it to work in a very hot environment.

Comment: @ThePhoton When ambient raises, then your thermal management must keep the circuit cooled.  Good luck to whoever would rather design a laser diode to work at 650° C.  Using solder would be a unique alternative method to wire bonding.